# Accidently dd to /dev/sda

Tags: kali-linux, dd, system-recovery

I used Kali Linux, and I accidently used dd to /dev/sda while I'm trying to backup my files.
It completes after a few seconds with a total size about 10 - 20 mb. After my computer was rebooted, it wouldn't boot, and the disk can't be read (corrupted). I immediately use SystemRescue disk and make a img copy of the corrupted disk.

I've tried using Testdisk and Photorec, and I got most of my files back (I think), I also used gdisk and got about 60% of my files in lost+found.

Is there any way to repair the partition table and make it bootable again, while I still have all my files like what it used to be?

fsck, e2fsck, fsck.ext4 not working.

Pls help, Thank you.

Comment: Please don't use 'debian' in the tags when you already admit that what you were actually using is Kali. They are very emphatically *not* the same.

Comment: Consider using a backup utility for performing backups. `dd` is not a backup utility.

Answer (score 6):

**TL;DR** Your system is hosed and you're going to have to reinstall from backup after moving whatever files you recovered and want to keep elsewhere.

`dd` is an extremely raw copy mechanism - it literally duplicates source to destination byte by byte, and when run as root there are *no* safeguards to do exactly what you did, because sometimes `dd if=file of=/dev/sda` is exactly what you want to do and it has never been Unix policy to ask you whether you *really* want to shoot yourself in the foot when you point the gun down and pull the trigger.

You completely overwrote the partition table and a fair chunk of the first partition at the disk level. Professional (IE, well paid and probably employed by agencies like the NSA) forensics might be able to recover a bit more by looking at the filesystem boundaries that you *didn't* overwrite, but doing so will take significantly more time, effort and resources than simply reinstalling would.

It *might* be possible, but it's not cost effective and you won't recover anything you already did.